# Adding a non-empty constraint to Email field

Tags: sql-server

I have a varchar email field in my table.  I can't figure out the syntax to add a constraint that ensures a non-empty value cannot be inserted.  I"m not talking about not null, I'm talking not empty here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

len(ltrim(rtrim(email))) <> 0

Answer (score 3):

Add a `not null` and a `check` constraint.

```
create table MyTable (
   email varchar(100) not null,
   constraint email_not_empty check (rtrim(ltrim(email)) != '')
)
```

Comment: Why do you need to ltrim and rtrim?  If it only contains whitespace then a single trim should reduce the length to zero, no?

Comment: @Darrel: I don't think T-SQL supported TRIM.

Comment: No it doesn't but you could use either ltrim or rtrim and it should work.